# A C*-algebra enjoying some different C*-norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Does there exist any  C*-algebra $(A,\|\cdot\|)$  enjoying  the following property?

$\bullet$  There exists a norm $|\cdot|$ on $A$ with $\|\cdot\|\leq|\cdot|$  such that   $(A,|\cdot|)$ is a  pre C*-algebra (necessarily non-complete).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No that's not possible (except the trivial case). Any $*$-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras is automatically contractive, and if it is injective then it is isometric. You can apply this to the identity map of $A$ seens as a map from $(A,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ to the completion of $(A,\vert \cdot \vert)$ and conclude that two norm are equal.

More concretely it follows from the fact that (for self adjoint elements) the norm in a $C^*$-algebra coincide with the spectral radius, which force relations between the two norm. Here it forces $\vert \cdot \vert \leqslant \Vert \cdot \Vert$ hence the equality of the two norms.

Comment: For another description of the norm derived only from the $\ast$-algebra structure, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414904/2362). In fact, the "pre-norm" coming from the $\ast$-algebra structure in this sense is quite robust -- it fails to be a submultiplicative seminorm on a general $\ast$-algebra only in that it can take the value $\infty$.

Comment: @ Tim Campion, The reference is so helpful. Thanks a lot.