# Definition of condensed $C^{\ast}$-algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, condensed-mathematics

The classical definition of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra is a Banach algebra with an isometric antilinear involution map $a \mapsto a^\ast$. What would be a good definition for a condensed $C^{\ast}$-algebra? How to make sense of properties like $\|a \cdot a^{\ast}\| = \|a\|^2$ and $\|a \cdot b\| \leq \|a\| \cdot \|b\|$?

Edit: Following the comment by Prof Simon Henry. A definition of condensed Banach algebra not using the norm would be nice.

Comment: Is there a notion of "condensed Banach algebra" that doesn't involve a norm function? Otherwise I'm not sure what's the problem with the two conditions you are mentioning.

Comment: The norm play a fairly essential role in the theory of C* algebra so I'm not sure a notion corresponding to just topological vector space is sufficient here. For e.g. injective morphisms of C*-algebras are automatically isometric - I'm not sure one can define a notion of C* algebra without including the norm function as part of the definition - at which point there is no difficulty including the two conditions you are talking about explicitly.

Comment: Though there are some way to characterize C*-algebra in a way not involving the norm, exploiting the fact that the norm can be defined using the spectral radius of $x^* x$. see for e.g. "a characterization of C* algebras" by Hennings , proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society (1987) 30, 445-4S3 (https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/F21346AE0A7277E09CDAB05B0D074445/S0013091500026845a.pdf/a-characterisation-of-c-algebras.pdf)

Comment: Nice, thank you for the comment! So the real question is whether there is a definition of condensed Banach Algebra not involving the norm.

Comment: I thought a "condensed XYZ" is just a sheaf on the pro-etale site in the category of XYZs. Then a condensed C* algebra would be a sheaf in the category of C* algebras.

Comment: @Echo I am not asking for the condensed C-star algebra, but the condensed analogue eg the condensed analogue of top vector space is condensed vector space and not condensed top vector space.

Comment: So given the context that a C*-algebra is a *-algebra satisfying an additional property, namely that the spectral radius formula defines a norm on the *-algebra and hence a topology, I am not sure what you are asking. Are you suggesting that there might be *-algebras for which the spectral radius formula does not make it into a Banach algebra, but there is still a natural way to make it into a condensed algebra?

Comment: Maybe the characterization of $C^\ast$-algebras given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414904/2362) might be helpful. First, you define what a $\ast$-algebra is (and this is purely algebraic, so presumably the definition can be reused verbatim in the condensed setting). Then you observe that every $\ast$-algebra $A$ has a canonically defined positive cone $A^+ = \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^\ast a_i \mid a_i \in A\}$, which induces a uniformity on $A$. Finally, you observe that $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra if and only if this uniform structure is separated and complete. (I'm not sure how to condensify.)

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a definition? C*-algebras are already (a full subcategory of) condensed sets/algebras/*-algebras. So what are you aiming for?